Ellipse area using geometric mean
While trying to prove that the area of an ellipse is $\pi ab$, I came across the idea of using geometric mean.
Suppose we have an ellipse with the semi-minor $b$ and semi-major $a$. Then construct 2 circles, of radii $a$ and $b$, centred at the same position as the ellipse (such that the smaller circle is inscribed in the ellipse and the bigger circle inscribes the ellipse). If the geometric mean of the 2 circles are taken, we indeed yield the area of the ellipse.
$$\sqrt{\pi a^2 \cdot \pi b^2} = \pi ab$$
The difficulty I am having is justifying this coincidence. How does this result relate to the formal definitions of the geometric mean?

The way I think about it is with scale factors.  Make a circle with a radius $b$, then stretch it in one dimension by the scale factor $\frac{a}{b}$ so the two radii in that dimension are now the semi-major axes with length $b\bigl(\frac{a}{b}\bigr) = a$.  Since this is happening in only one dimension (rather than two, as when doubling the side length of a square), the area also scales by this factor, so the area of the ellipse is $\pi b^2\bigl(\frac{a}{b}\bigr) = \pi ab$.

This seems indeed just a coincidence, to prove the expression we can observe that for a circle
$$x^2+y^2=a^2$$
the area is $\pi a^2$ then by a dilation along $y$ that is $x=\bar x $ and $y=\frac a b \bar y$ we obtain the ellipse
$$\frac{\bar x^2}{a^2}+\frac{\bar y^2}{b^2}=1$$
then
$$d\bar A = d\bar x d \bar y = \frac  b adxdy=\frac b a dA$$
then
$$\bar A = A\frac b a =\pi a^2\frac b a = \pi a b$$
